# Getting problem with sendPayment method in cardano-wallet-js

Tags: cardano-address

I am following (https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardano-wallet-js/) this document for development using cardano-wallet-js. And using below script for sendPayment, but getting error to send payments.

import fetch from 'node-fetch';
const walletId = "b2eaa569bf27180c9806783bdd75dd145e216ae2";

const resp = await fetch(`http://0.0.0.0:8236/v2/wallets/${walletId}`);
const wallet = await resp.json();

let receiverAddress = [new AddressWallet('addr_test1qzhg95y7f9kh23qwu0hmnncs8lg3ezk2vw5980e27cmv2cn4r5r6cmxxf3qqhhz49shud34ye7ppk3gq5zu7gagd2wzs6v2zcs')];
let amounts = [5000000]; // 5 ADA
let transaction = await wallet.sendPayment(receiverAddress,amounts);

**Error:---**

let transaction = await wallet.sendPayment(receiverAddress,amounts);
^

TypeError: wallet.sendPayment is not a function
at file:///home/ubuntu/cardano-git-repo/cardano_raw_api/scripts/sendtoaddress.js:12:32
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v18.18.0